# How to print a field content link in the views-view-field template in Drupal 7?

Tags: views, entities, theming

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to print the content link of a field in the Views' template.

I would like to link an article title to its node, something like the following code:

```
print '<a href="' . $node_url . '">' . $article['und']['0']['value'] . '</a>'
```

This is a dumbed down version of my code in the view-view-field--field-article-title.tpl.php

```
$article = $row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_article_title;
$subtitle = $row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_article_subtitle;

if (isset($subtitle['und']['0']['value'])) {
  print $article['und']['0']['value'] . ': ' . $subtitle['und']['0']['value'] . '</p>';
}
else {   
  print $article['und']['0']['value'];
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've tried printing out the available fields, but for some reason I cannot print the fields in the view.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an expert and this may not be the absolute best way, but it works for me in D7 view-view-field templates.

Include something like this in your template file

```
<a href="<?php print base_path().drupal_get_path_alias("node/{$row->nid}") ?>">...</a>
```